# Test for differences in two sets of correlation values

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, anova, pearson-r

```
A.cor <- as.numeric(c("1","0.99","0.99","1","0.99","0.99","0.96","0.99","0.99","0.98","1","0.99","0.99","0.99","0.99","0.99","0.98","0.96","0.99","0.98"))
B.cor <- as.numeric(c("0.98","0.98","0.98","0.98","0.97","0.97","0.95","0.98","0.97","0.98","0.98","0.98","0.98","0.99","0.97","0.97","0.96","0.97","0.97","0.98"))
```

I have two sets of pearson correlation values. 
One of the vectors are the same for the calculation of A.cor and B.cor. like this: A/C and B/C, where C is used in both.

I would like to test if they are significantly different from each other? Which test is most correct to use? I considered using ANOVA.

Comment: The elements of each dataset independent or not?  For instance, often (large) sets of correlations arise from a matrix of correlations between multiple variables--but those correlations are strongly interdependent.

Comment: I would say the are not completly independent as one of the vectors are the same for the calculation of A.cor and B.cor. like this:  A/C and  B/C, where C is used in both.

Comment: That's crucial information.  Please include it in an edit to your question and provide enough details for people to understand exactly how these numbers are related.

Comment: could you suggest a method as well?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_correlation_of_ratios